# How to solve Assembly.Load performance hit?

Tags: .net, assemblies, assembly.load

I'm refactoring some code and I've been hit with a dilemma.

Let's say we have the following scenario:

1. A Core Assembly that contains many common interfaces and classes
2. A Library Assembly that contains more specialized classes.

The Library Assembly references the Core Assembly. So far so good.

Due the fact that I'm refactoring this, there's a need for the Core Assembly to create objects that are declared in the Library Assembly.

OK, in order to avoid a circular reference problem, I decided to load the Library Assembly when needed (and it's needed only in  a very specific point at the type initialization).

However, the loading performance of the whole thing plummeted to a dark abyss...

Does anyone know how to solve this?

---

**Edited to add**

Some people have requested the code I use to load... It's quite trivial, really.

```
/*
 * Load the Library Assembly
 */
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("Library, PublicKeyToken=...");

/*
 * Get desired type
 */
Type   t = asm.GetType("Library.DesiredType")

/*
 * Get the default constructor
 */
var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] {})
```

Comment: Really, performance became unacceptable by loading a single assembly at start-up? How big is this assembly?

Comment: It's ridiculous small: 52K (52,224 bytes)

Comment: If you're refactoring anyway, why not refactor the common dependencies into a 3rd assembly so you don't have a circular dependency problem and thus don't need to rely on dynamic loading?

Comment: @Aaronaught OP used a poor wording to describe the situation, but aside from the scary words "circular reference", the scenario is a totally legit setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assembly should only be loaded once into the AppDomain. Repeat calls to load assembly X should return the already-loaded assembly. <strike>Can you post the code for how you're attempting this?</strike> How are you measuring "performance"? Have you profiled your application to verify the performance hit is indeed coming from loading the assembly?

Comment: You're right, the problem wasn't the assembly loading. it was completely unrelated... So, back to the drawing board!